# Android get position of view for animation start point

Tags: android, animation

Hi i'm trying to create an animation with the current position as start point

```
    Animation outAnimation = new TranslateAnimation(
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, 0.0f,
            Animation.ABSOLUTE, overlay.getTranslationY(),
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_PARENT, +1.0f);
    outAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
    outAnimation.setDuration(1500);
    outAnimation.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
```

overlay is a LinearLayout with a RelativeLayout as parent.

but overlay.getTranslationY() returns 0, though it is currently placed on the bottom of the RelativeLayout (through an animation)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/realtiveArea"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/titlebar"
        android:layout_marginTop="-12dp" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/overlayText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running Animation (and not Animator), the actual position of your View (`getY()`) is not animated, only the drawing of the view is animated with Animation. You can try logging 'getTop()', 'getTranslationY()' and 'getY()' during the animation. None of these will change)

I highly suggest you to switch to Animator (and using the ViewPropertyAnimator API when possible).

Your entire OutAnimation could be rewritten as :

```
overlay.animate()
  .translationY(overlay.getRootView().getHeight()
        - overlay.getTop()
        - getHeight())
  .setDuration(1500)
  .setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
```

You probably will have to change your InAnimation in order to have consistant behavior for the in and out animation. Feel free to post the InAnimation.

Animators are available from API 11, but since you are using `getTranslationY()`, you are probably already building upon API >11.

Comment: i used .translationY(0) for scroll in and .translationY(overlay.getHeight()) for scroll out now

Comment: is is possible to set the initial y translation in onCreate of my activity?

Comment: Ofc, just use `overlay.setTranslationY()`. But you need to be aware that during onCreate, the view won't be measured, then if you do something like `overlay.setTranslationY(overlay.getHeight())`, it won't work because the height will be 0. To overcome this, you should pre-positioned the view just before the draw is performed. Google for `View.getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener();` This is the preferred solution to perform graphical stuff just before the drawing.

Answer (score 0):

`overlay.getTranslationY()` returns the translationY attribute. What you need is `overlay.getY()`.

Comment: overlay.getY() gives me 220... this is too less... since it is located on the bottom of the screen currently

Comment: Could you share your layout xml file?

Comment: seems that the 220 is the original position, it does not respect the translated position by a previous animation

Comment: 'overlay' is the LinearLayout from the provided xml?